# How does Node bcrypt hashing/compare work since the salt is unknown

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I was looking at the code example in bcrypt docs:

```
bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
  // Store hash in your password DB.
});
```

What I do not understand is how do I compare the passwords if I dont know the salts?

```
bcrypt.compare(myPlaintextPassword, hash, function(err, res) {
    // res == true
});
```

After some reading, I learnt that the `hash` contains the salt and cost already. But if thats the case, once a hacker, gets this hash he can already bruteforce the passwords maybe using rainbow tables or something?

Isit it a better practice to store the hash and salt separately?

Is this a secure way of handling passwords?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've misunderstood the security provided by a salt. There is no expectation or intention that the salt will be kept secret from an attacker -- if an attacker gets the hashed passwords, they will get the salt as well. But it still prevents them from using a rainbow table or other pre-calculated attack, because they won't have a rainbow table that was generated using that specific salt. They can run a brute-force attack, of course, but bcrypt has other features to make that difficult.